# Division of responsibilities for loadView() and viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

In a project I'm working on, I have a view controller which overrides the `loadView()` method for setting up the view hierarchy programatically. I was curious if there are requirements regarding what goes in this method versus in `viewDidLoad()`, or if the latter is redundant when `loadView()` is already overridden. Is there anything that *cannot* be done e.g. at the very end of `loadView()` that should be deferred until `viewDidLoad()` is called, or is it simply a matter of preference?

EDIT: The initial phrasing of this question was somewhat opinion based. To clarify, I'm interested in whether there is any reference material indicating that there are technical limitations regarding methods that are not able to be used in `loadView()` that can be used in `viewDidLoad()`.

Comment: If there's anything that *cannot* be done, is that you don't call that method yourself. I'm not sure if setting up your views on your controller in one of these methods is based on preferences. All of my subviews are in the `viewDidLoad()`. I've seen people adding their views in `loadView()`.

Comment: A quick google search for `viewdidload vs loadview` gives lots of articles and discussions.

Comment: Yes, I've already read the top few articles/threads in that search. I've edited to clarify my question, but I'm more interested in whether there is any sort of behind-the-scenes UIKit initialization between the two methods that makes certain methods inappropriate or unusable in `loadView()` but not in `viewDidLoad()`. None of the things that I read say much more than "Use `loadView()` if you're not using a xib or story board file; I usually put the subviews in `viewDidLoad()`."

Comment: Note that `loadView` is _always_ called; the default implementation does important work (like looking for the view in an associated nib).

Comment: If you have a xib or a storyboard, don't touch `loadView`. If you set up everything in code, there is no need to touch `loadView` if the controller's view class is supposed to be `UIView`. Only override `loadView` if you are setting up views in code and only if `view` should be a custom class, e.g. `UITableView`.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for `loadView` pretty much answers your question:

> If you use Interface Builder to create your views and initialize the view controller, you must not override this method.
>
> You can override this method in order to create your views manually. If you choose to do so, assign the root view of your view hierarchy to the view property. The views you create should be unique instances and should not be shared with any other view controller object. Your custom implementation of this method should not call super.
>
> If you want to perform any additional initialization of your views, do so in the viewDidLoad() method.

In other words, only ever override `loadView` if you are writing your view controller strictly in code - no nib or storyboard. And then only if you have a reason for the base view of the controller to be something other than a plain old `UIView` that you get by default. And remember that you must *not* call `super.loadView()` in your implementation.

I would use `viewDidLoad` to create and setup any subviews you wish to add to the base view of the view controller (whether `loadView` was used or not). Also use `viewDidLoad` for any other setup that can't be done until the view has been loaded.

Technically, if you override `loadView` to setup a custom base view, anything you might have put in `viewDidLoad` can be put in your `loadView`. But I would still separate the responsibility. Only use `loadView` (if needed) to create and setup the base view of the controller. Use `viewDidLoad` to create other subviews as needed and any other controller setup.

Also keep in mind that some view controller initial setup belongs in the initializer. But such code can't make any reference to any views.

Comment: I've read the `loadView()` documentation, but the [`viewDidLoad()` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621495-viewdidload) seems slightly contradictory: "You usually override this method to perform additional initialization on views that were loaded from nib files." To me, this suggests that if you're overriding `loadView()` (and implicitly, not loading from a nib file), you should not be using `viewDidLoad()` at all. I've edited the question to clarify that I'm more interested in whether there are any technical limitations between the two methods.

Comment: @Jumhyn And even that is somewhat misleading, because people take that as license to do things like adding masks or sublayers to their views, or positioning views manually, not realizing that `viewDidLoad` is too early for that. Basically I would say everything in its place: `loadView` is your chance to supply the main view differently from how the default implementation would supply it, but I wouldn't do anything else there.

Comment: `viewDidLoad` should be used (whether `loadView` is used or not, or whether nibs are used or not) to create/adjust any subviews you might need to add or any other setup needed.

Comment: I think that feels a little stringent. With a nib, `loadView()` creates the whole view hierarchy, subviews included. Seems like that should be the case for a custom `loadView()` implementation as well. In any case, it seems like the answer to the rephrased question is "No," unless I'm misinterpreting? If you edit your answer to address the edited question a little more directly and leave the rest as clarification, I'll accept!